# Version One 401 - Unauthorized: "Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: versionone

I'm developing an angular application and I'm using Version One Rest API.

When I make the rest calls directly in the browser url using the company domain everything works fine.

The problem is when I try to make HTTP requests from external applications, this  server error message appears:

**Version One 401 - Unauthorized: "Access is denied due to invalid credentials.**

A public application was created using 'Access Token' authentication, and the company's Version One Instance uses the Windows Automatic Authentication.
And I'm sending the request with the 'Authorization: Bearer + Token' in the Header.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was just a CORS issue, after add **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** to the server configuration the problem was solved.